# Amazon Aurora requests per second

Tags: mysql, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-aurora

I am researching if DynamoDB or Amazon Aurora best suits for my service.

DynamoDB is capable of serving thousands of requests per second without capacity planning.

Is there a limit on number of requests Amazon Aurora can serve? I am looking through documentation and could not find any limit.

I read upto 15 replicas can be added for high availability.

Answer (score 0):

To directly answer your question, if you are using Aurora's data API which is likened to how you would interact with DynamoDB, you are capped at 1000 RPS. With DynamoDB there is no limit, it can scale to millions of RPS and more.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/CHAP_Limits.html

---

Before trying to understand if Aurora has a limit, it would be best to ask yourself what are your application needs:

1. Is your workload OLAP or OLTP?
2. What is your upper bound throughput requirements?
3. What is your upper bound data storage requirements?
4. What is you latency needs?

---

Below you can see some differences in the two databases:

[image]